# MSBuild, FxCop and StyleCop integration with CruiseControl.Net

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I had already integrated MSBuild, FxCop and StyleCop with CruiseControl.Net, however i am facing some problem related logfile, it contains lot informations due to that the size of the file is around 150 mb , but i want only error and warning so that it can easly load in CruiseControl.Net Dashboard

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you rephrase it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify the settings of your msbuild fxcop and stylecop tasks. Thus, you will cut off the size of the xml logs produced by these tasks and the size of your merged xml log. It will be easier to view it in the dashboard.

- MsBuild : Add /v:m (for verbosity=minimal) to the arguments.
- FxCop : see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstscode/thread/3f8931da-9a4d-47a6-b331-8b6b07aea8d6
- StyleCop : doesn't know how to adjust verbosity.